# choice the database. iOS

Tags: ios, database

I am making meeting app and I need to store users data. I am not need to use sql for now because it hard to setting it, so I need place to store data, I not want store users in RAM, so where can I do it? It not necessary to cache images for now, by if I can add it in this place in future it will be great.

Comment: I apologize for the comment that was just made (if anyone actually saw it), my friend got a hold of my account and sent it.  I will be more careful with letting people touch my computer next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe you are asking:

```
 I am developing a meeting app and I need to store some user data. 
 I dont want to use sql for because its complex to do, so I need 
 a place to store my data. I not want use up unnecessary RAM, 
 so where can I store the data? I currently dont have any need 
 for cacheing images but perhaps in the future.
```

Not using CoreData/SQL because its hard to understand is not really a good reason. It was the native built in way of data access within iOS and it is the recommended way.

This is a very broad question since we dont know what your data looks like and if there are relationships between them, how large your dataset is, etc.

If its a small enough data list maybe you can look into using a `PLIST`. It will be a list of values with a key to each one. If its really small you can use `NSUserDefaults` If its static data, perhaps storing them in a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`